# Array of numbers and their sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, summation, contest-math, summation-method

> Consider the following $3 \times 2$ array formed by using the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$:
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}\\ a_{31} & a_{32} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 6\\ 2 & 5\\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Observe that all row sums are equal, but the sum of the squares is not the same for each row. Extend the above array to a $3 × k$ array ${(a_{ij})_{3×k}}$ for a suitable k, adding more columns, using the numbers $7,8,9,..., 3k$ such that
>
> $$\sum_{j=1}^k a_{1i}=\sum_{j=1}^k a_{2i}=\sum_{j=1}^k a_{3i}$$
>
> $$and$$
>
> $$\sum_{j=1}^k a_{1i}^2 = \sum_{j=1}^k a_{2i}^2 = \sum_{j=1}^k a_{3i}^2$$

I basically know its answer now. This was an olympiad problem and I did proceed in the right direction to solve it but I don't know what actually happened in the last step(s). I just got a small silly equation which did not give any solution to the question.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Can you help me out in the LaTeX of the summation part. I'm not finding any error in it...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks, done!

Comment: Please show your work and where you got stuck.